# How to connect to Flickr's Search Image API from Android app?

Tags: java, android, api, rest, flickr

I'm trying to create an Android app using Android Studio, where a user can search for images by typing text into a search bar. the App is supposed to be connected to an image search API, and I chose Flickr. I have never worked with anything like this before, and I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to start? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to start from [Flick API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) and know the necessary endpoints. Then you also need a networking library like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html). Finally I'll advice you use JSON for request and response formats.